# Modifying BERT tokens

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers

Is there any way to change a token text for a specific ID on a pre-trained BERT family model on a Huggingface tokenizer? Let's assume I want to assign the ID of the string "TOKEN_ONE" to the string "TOKEN_TWO" for a certain research reason. Is there any way to force the BERT tokenizer to assign the id corresponding to the "TOKEN_ONE" whenever it sees "TOKEN_TWO"?